# Sliding background image right to left then back from left to right

Tags: css

I have this code which I call from css that slides from right to left. how would I go about sliding it back right after the right to left animation?

```
-webkit-animation: slide 5s linear infinite;
//like to slide back right after same speed and position

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  from {
    background-position: -60px, -20px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -170px, -20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: add `alternate` to the animation

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to alternate

```css
div {
  animation: slide 5s linear infinite;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/50x50);
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-position: -60px, -20px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: -170px, -200px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -60px, -20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```